# Align an Icon to the top left of multiline UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

On the top left on a UILabel I want to align an Icon. This works file but if the Label has multiple lines the UIImage is aligned in the middle of the UILabel. There are option on interface builder such as first base line, but what I need is something like first line center Y. Is there something similar?

Comment: Try to add center vertically constraint from image to label!!

Comment: This is what I did. It works if the label has only one line. If multiple lines then the image is centered in the middle of the lable, not in the middle of the first line

Comment: Then try to add top constraint with your constant value!!

Comment: There is no default constraint exist for your requirement try to fix placement of your icon manually such as it looks centre for first line of label. Don't make any relational constraints with your label.

Comment: I think the best you can do is using the first baseline constraint and compensate the height of the image (which can be different than the height 1 line of text) with the constraint's constant value to make it centered on the first line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make the first line of label in the same centre position of another UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830148/how-to-make-the-first-line-of-label-in-the-same-centre-position-of-another-uivie)

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a way of doing this! If you use AutoLayout this can be done with the following snippet:

```swift
// Aligns the icon to the center of a capital letter in the first line
let offset = label.font.capHeight / 2.0

// Aligns the icon to the center of the whole line, which is different
// than above. Especially with big fonts this makes a visible difference.
let offset = (label.font.ascender + label.font.descender) / 2.0

let constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
  imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.firstBaselineAnchor, constant: -offset),
  imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.leadingAnchor, constant: -10)
]
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

The first constraint will display your icon at the Y center of the first line of your label. The second one puts your icon left of the label and creates a 10pt space between them.

Answer (score -3):

[image]

Just put constraints as shown in the above image.

Hint: I made label's lines property value to 5 which supports upto 5 lines without any compromise.