# how to make the first line of label in the same centre position of another UIView

Tags: ios, autolayout

[image]

I want to make the first line of those words (I am using UI Label here, or should I use Text View?), in the center of red line, the center of that red line is located at the center of that yellow UIView

I have tried some autolayout configuration but still failed to achieve this
[image]

Comment: You have leading space set to 8 points from the view.

Comment: Change bottom space constraint to `greater than or equal to`. Multiline `UILabel` are usually not fixed by both top and bottom space. Better let it grows itself. If you do want to fix the view size or the text may be longer than the viewport, you should use `UITextView`.

Comment: Can't you just add some margin above the label, i.e. by setting the top constraint constant to something other than 0?

Comment: You can create a 0 height view that centre align vertically to the yellow view, then set the top space of the `UILable` to the 0 height view as 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an involved process. Take your time to understand the whole logic.

First of all we have some considerations:

- The **Yellow** view has a defined height (as well as a defined width, so that it's horizontal center can be determined)
- The label has a fixed font size (so that the horizontal center of first line can be aligned with the horizontal center of the **Yellow** view by means of constraint)

---

We will add a placeholder view to the right hand side of the **Yellow** view and make them center aligned. Here comes the handy `UIStackView`.

We take a `UIStackView` with these properties:

- Axis: `Horizontal`
- Alignment: `Center`
- Distribution: `Fill`
- Spacing: **As your need**

The above stack view uses the Auto Layout:

- Leading, Trailing, Top: With respect to the super view (view controller's view / safe area)
- Height: A fixed height (this will be the height of the **Yellow** view)

These are the constraints for the stack view:

[image: stack view constraints]

Now we will add two views to the stack view with the attributes:

- **Yellow** view:

  - Width: A fixed width
  - Height: Equal to the height of the stack view
  - But note that, I used a width & aspect ratio constraint so that the view remains rectangular
- Placeholder view:

  - Height: 0

These are the constraints for the two views:

[image: two views' constraints]

Now comes the label's part. It's a multiline label (number of lines set to `0`) The label will be aligned with the placeholder view by top, leading & trailing constraints. But the top constraints need a slight consideration. The label will have a font size of `20` so that if the top constraint has `-13` (not `-10` because there is a top padding between the label's frame and label's text) value with the placeholder, then it can be aligned with the horizontal center of the **Yellow** view.

These are the constraints for the label:

[image: label's constraints]

---

Enough of the talking. I have made a demo which you'll find [here](https://github.com/M-I-N/CenterAlignedLabel). Also keep in mind *if you need to control the horizontal space between the yellow view and the label, you can achieve that by changing the spacing value of the stack view.*

Also keep in mind that, this implementation is very tightly configured. Anything changes, everything breaks. But if your need is slightly changed so that *the first line of the label is vertically aligned (not the horizontal center of the first line)* you can forget about the font size of the label and the `-13` top constraint's value.

---

Below is the final output. I added a horizontal redline to indicate the middle of the yellow view.

[image]

Comment: If you need a placeholder view and then some padding to account for the label height, you might as well just pin the top of the label to the yellow view, and then add some padding until it looks right.

Comment: The initial statement that font size is fixed will make end users with poor eye sight not. Like your app. As it is good practice for apps to auto adjust font when user goes into settings and sets accessibilty big fonts enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this recently in a slightly less involved way by adding a **hidden single line label** in exactly the same location and font as the multiline one, **without a bottom constraint.**

Then you can simply align the icon image `.centerY` to the hidden label's `.centerY`.

```
self.view.addConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: icon,
        attribute: .centerY,
        relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: hiddenLabel,
        attribute: .centerY,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0
    )
)
```

[image: multi line label icon alignment]

Answer (score 1):

For aligning with the first line of a multi-line labels, you should use the constraint `NSLayoutAttributeFirstBaseline` (avail in iOS8) or the anchor on `UIView` `firstBaselineAnchor` (avail in iOS9).